# pickle error with multiprocessing and cv2

Tags: python, opencv, multiprocessing

I'm trying to implement a code that takes a video and divides it into frames while also filtering the frames and saving them to a different directory.
I am running into an error that says:

> TypeError: cannot pickle 'cv2.VideoCapture' object

I have tried to understand why this problem occurs but I'm still unsure why.

here is my code:

```
import cv2
import os
import time
import matplotlib.image as pltim
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def saveFramesUnfiltered(vid, lock):
    currentFrame = 0  # counter for frames (to organize them by order)

    while True:
        success, frame = vid.read()
        lock.acquire()
        cv2.imwrite("./framesBefore/frame" + str(currentFrame) + '.jpg',
                frame)  # save unfiltered frame to folder and show the video (using the frames)
        lock.release()

        currentFrame = currentFrame + 1

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break  # end loop when finished
        time.sleep(0.01)


def saveFramesFiltered(lock):
    currentFrame = 0
    framemax = 215
    while currentFrame < framemax:
        if os.path.exists("framesBefore/frame" + str(currentFrame) + '.jpg'):
            lock.acquire()
            image = pltim.imread("./framesBefore/frame" + str(currentFrame) + '.jpg')
            lock.release()
            r, g, b = image[:, :, 0], image[:, :, 1], image[:, :, 2]
            grayImage = 0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b
            plt.plot(grayImage, cmap="gray")
            plt.axis("off")
            lock.acquire()
            plt.savefig("./framesAfter/grayImage" + str(currentFrame) + ".jpg", bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
            lock.release()
            time.sleep(0.01)


def main():
    if not os.path.exists('framesBefore'):
        os.makedirs('framesBefore')  # create a folder for the unfiltered frames

    if not os.path.exists('framesAfter'):
        os.makedirs('framesAfter')  # create a folder for the filtered frames

    lock = Lock()
    vid = cv2.VideoCapture("maxwell cat.mp4")  # getting the video

    unfiltered_process = Process(target=saveFramesUnfiltered, args=(vid, lock))
    filtered_process = Process(target=saveFramesFiltered, args=lock)

    unfiltered_process.start()
    filtered_process.start()

    unfiltered_process.join()
    filtered_process.join()

    vid.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()  # clear memory


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am also new at using threads in python and in general so I would like to know if the way I implemented it is correct.
thanks!

Comment: those camera objects are not to be moved between processes. you are doing multiprocessing there, not multithreading. you should read all the frames from a single function, and then distribute the frames to different threads/processes, using a Pool Executor (threadpool or other)

Comment: Just move `vid = cv2.VideoCapture("maxwell cat.mp4")` inside `saveFramesUnfiltered`. It can't be transferred to the child, but it can be created there. You may also want to investigate using `multiprocessing.shared_memory` to transfer frames to the other process if you find writing then reading from disk is too slow.